Do we need the medication tag?
Just noticed the tag medication on one of the new questions, was suspicious about it, and noticed it is not used often. Possibly there are more appropriate/related tags we already have for this?

I edited it out of both.  
I don't think it's a good tag, since psychopharmacology already covers psychoactive medications, and that is a term that an expert might search for on Google.
I don't think it needs to be blacklisted, but we can watch for it and see if it comes back.

Another advantage for 'psychopharmacology' over 'medication' is that the former is much less likely to promote self-help questions than the latter, and we want to avoid self-help questions.

An excellent point, @ArtemKaznatcheev.
